# Error when using "..." as the input for a function

Tags: r

```
data_generate<-function(length, per,   dist = c("gaussian", "exponential"),..., 
outdist=c("gaussian", "exponential"),... ){
outdist <- match.arg(outdist) outlier=per*length/100
if(dist=="gaussian"){ 
data <- rnorm(length,...)
if(outdist=="normal"){ 
ot <- rnorm(outlier,...) }
else{ot <- rexp(outlier,...) } 
dist <- length/outlier out1<-seq(start, length, by = dist)
out2 <- seq(start, 0, by= -dist) outlier<-unique(c(out1,out2))
out <- outlier
data[out] <- ot print(data) }else{ if (dist=="exponential"){ 
dist <- match.arg(dist)
```

In this R function, I'm trying to develop a function that generates data which includes outliers. Distribution of generated data is optional (Gaussian and exponential) and the distribution of outliers are optional too. I get error

> Error: repeated formal argument '...'"

because I use the same kind of arguments such as "..." as the input, how can I solve this problem, could you help me, please?

Comment: REST of the code is below,     outdist <- match.arg(outdist)
outlier=per*length/100
 if(dist=="gaussian"){
 data<-rnorm(length,...)
  if(outdist=="normal"){
  ot<-rnorm(outlier,...)
  }else{
  ot<-rexp(outlier,...)
  }
 dist<-length/outlier
 out1<-seq(start, length, by = dist)
 out2<-seq(start, 0, by= -dist)
 outlier<-unique(c(out1,out2))
 out<-outlier
 data[out]<-ot 
 print(data)
 }else{
if (dist=="exponential"){

Comment: Only use `...` once.

Comment: Is it your impression somehow that adding ... after an argument makes it optional? That's not what ... is for.

Comment: using once is solution but there are 2 optinonal arguments in the function, how can i manage that problem

Comment: optional argument means, user can choose a distribution of dataset (normal or exponential and different parameters for them) and distribution of certain number of outliers.